# JSONDecode error during decoding the content in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a bunch of Python scripts that was running yesterday perfectly. In order to deploy this to the web server, I extracted all the scripts in one single file to make it easy.

I am using Pycharm for all executions. In local computer executions with folder structure, same scripts work fine. Then, I extract the data into a single file and correct some import statements etc.

I get this error:

```
 File "/Users/mac/Documents/local_node_red/EdgeProcessor.py", line 336, in <module>
 myEdge = EdgeProcessor(speed_logging=False, output_format='turtle', debug_mode=False, timing=False)
 File "/Users/mac/Documents/local_node_red/EdgeProcessor.py", line 96, in __init__
 self.row = jsonpickle.loads(requests.get('http://' + self.APIAddr + ':' + str(self.APIPort)).content)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonpickle/unpickler.py", line 40, in decode
data = backend.decode(string)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonpickle/backend.py", line 194, in decode
raise e
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonpickle/backend.py", line 191, in decode
return self.backend_decode(name, string)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonpickle/backend.py", line 203, in backend_decode
return self._decoders[name](string, *optargs, **decoder_kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 5 (char 5)
```

I am new in Python. I believe only thing I did different here to update my jsonpickle library because the Pycharm and terminal was using different python interpretations. Even though version 1.1 and 1.2 was used before without any problems. So I don't think that it is the issue. Any ideas?

The problem still occurs when I go back to old version. Also, the problem occurs in my Raspberry Pi distributed executions since I didn't even touch it. When I try to execute it

I get this error

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 2)
```

The problematic code block is this.

```
self.row = jsonpickle.loads(
        requests.get('http://' + self.APIAddr + ':' + str(self.APIPort) + '/preprocessing').content)
```

It has no problems with the local executions, and had no problems in Raspberry Pi yesterday, I might have broken something unintentionally or I can't see the reason. Is there any other way do similar thing instead of jsonpickle?

Comment: What kind of address and port are you using?

Comment: What kind of data come from specified address?

Comment: locahost '127.0.0.1' and port 8080. When it is in raspberry pi, multicast ip and raspberries own ip. Like I said the jsonpickle was not a problem so far. In fact it still works as the same code when I launch with my local address in a folder structure. everything gets messed up, when I take them out from their folders. only this script doesn't work which might have some dependencies but what is the matter with jsonpickle?

Comment: tuple are coming after the semantic representation to split them and print afterwards.

Comment: Can you show the JSON document before you pass it to `jsonpickle.loads`?